# java escape unicode to char php

Tags: php, unicode

I am working on a webapp and need to display a string of text from the database.

Now I ran in to the problem that my sting contains unicodes like `\u0099`. I am using c# to put data in the database and thik it is an java escape unicode from doing my reserch.

`\u0099` is the `TM` char when put in. How can I make it so that php makes the sttring so that it uses characters instead of an unicode.

String example:

`$string = "This is my string :) company_name\u0099";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$string = "This is my string :) company_name\u0099";
$decoded = preg_replace('/\\\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/', '&#x\\1;', $string);
echo mb_convert_encoding($decoded, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```